# How to rename files with sequential names to an another sequence using Terminal?

Tags: bash, rename, file-management

I have a directory that has files in it that are named 'o1.ray' to 'o293.ray'. I want to move them to an another directory while renaming them 'o132.ray' to 'o424.ray'.

How can I do this in the terminal?

```
cd directory
for i in {1...293};
do cp o$i.ray subdirectory/o$i+131.ray;
done
```

I know this is wrong because I get:

```
error message 'cp: cannot stat 'o{1...293}.ray': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Assuming `bash` (you don't say). Double dots only in `{1..293}`. Double quotes around string that contain variable expansions. And `$(( i + 131 ))` is an arithmetic expansion. Use `cp -i` for safety. I won't turn this into an answer as it's mainly about syntax.

Comment: @michael-prokopec - careful adding the bash tag, unless it's absolutely clear from the OP that bash is involved. It's *probably* involved here, but let's be certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kusalananda hinted at, this is mostly an adjustment of syntax:

```
for index in {1..293}; do echo mv o"${index}".ray subdirectory/o"$((index+131))".ray; done
```

Remove the `echo` when the output looks correct.

Or, with zsh's [zmv module](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Misc/zmv):

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n 'o(<->).ray' 'subdirectory/o$[$1 + 131].ray'
```

The `$[ ... ]` syntax performs arithmetic; `$1` is captured with the parenthesis around the `<->` that follows the `o`. The `<->` is a zsh wildcard that captures numeric ranges; without any endpoints, it's open-ended; for your case, you could be very specific with:

```
zmv -n 'o(<1-293>).ray' 'subdirectory/o$[$1 + 131].ray'
```

Remove the `-n` when the output looks correct.