# Changing numbers in name of the file using terminal

Tags: rename

I have a large number of files with names *file00.txt*, *file01.txt* etc in a folder. Is it possible to rename all where the numbers will change to (4000+200*number) in terminal? I want the name of the final files as *file4000.txt*, *file4200.txt* etc. Thanks!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using so we can know what tools you have available. For example, there are many tools called `rename` and if we don't know your OS, we won't know which one you have.

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as [How to rename files with sequential names to an another sequence using Terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498923/how-to-rename-files-with-sequential-names-to-an-another-sequence-using-terminal), with slightly different arithmetic and without the subdirectory.

Answer (score 7):

If you have `zsh` installed...

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(file)(<->)(.txt)' '$1$((4000+$2*200))$3'
```

remove the `-n` if you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 6):

I would normally use `rename` which makes use of [`perlre`](https://manpages.org/perlre)

```
$ rename -v 's/^(file)(\d+)(\.txt)$/$1 . (4000+200*$2) . $3/e' *.txt
file00.txt renamed as file4000.txt
file01.txt renamed as file4200.txt
```

or as Glenn Jackman suggests in the comments;

```
$ rename -v 's/(\d+)/4000 + 200*$1/e' file*.txt
```

Explanation:

This uses the `s/foo/bar/` syntax which substitutes `foo` with `bar`.

`foo` is `^(file)(\d+)(.txt)`.  So the expression will match any file starting with `foo`, containing 1 or more digits, followed by a `.txt` extension and nothing else.  `file` is saved in capture group 1, the digits in capture group 2, and `.txt` in capture group 3.

Then we replace `bar` with our new filename:  `$1 . (4200 + $2) . $3`.  We are adding 4200 to capture group 2 (the digits) and concatenating that with `$1` and `$3`.

We need the `e` modifier in `s/foo/bar/e` to ensure `(4000 + 200*$2)` and the concatenation is actually evaluated.

I added `-v` so it prints what is changed, but while testing, you'll want to use `-n` so it doesn't change anything until you are happy with what it will actually do.

The last argument to the `rename` command is `*.txt`.  This is simply the list of files to evaluate.  Since we do a check for the extension in `perlre`, we could just use a `*` here.  Anything that doesn't match (`foo`) will not be changed.

This answer uses `file-rename` from Debian's package [rename](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/rename) which uses `update-alternatives` to provide `/usr/bin/rename`.  If you don't have that package installed, you may have `rename.ul` from [util-linux](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux).  `rename.ul` uses different expression system and will not work with what I've described here.

Comment: Can be slightly simplified: `rename -v 's/(\d+)/4000 + 200*$1/e' file*.txt` (fixed the formula in passing)

Comment: Note that this assumes `perl-rename`, while on many systems, the `rename` command is actually rename from util-linux instead. Oh, and the OP wants `4000 + (200 * $2)`, so not adding 4200, but adding 4000 to the result of multiplying the number by 200.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rename *all* of the files and you just want to rename *some* of the files within a *certain range*, then a modified version of the solution from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499046/97255) to [How to rename files with sequential names to an another sequence using Terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498923/97255) may be of some use.

For example, to rename just `file05.txt` through to `file11.txt` to `file5000.txt` to `file7200.txt`:

```
for index in {05..11}; do echo mv file"${index}".txt file"$((4000+index*200))".txt; done
```

The `echo` is there just to test that the command does what you expect it to. Remove the `echo` once the output looks correct.

##### Note for single digits (numbers <10)

For the files in the `file01.txt` to `file09.txt` range, a `0` must be added to precede the single digit in the range. Therefore, instead of

```
for index in {5..11};
```

you would put

```
for index in {05..11};
```

For a range of double digits, then the preceding `0` is not required. For example, for 13 to 25:

```
for index in {13..25};
```